# For $k\in \mathbb{N}$, let... $a_k := \left|\frac{1}{k}-\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right|$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For $k\in \mathbb{N}$, let $a_k := \left|\frac{1}{k}-\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right|$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_k = 0$. Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}a_k$ diverges. Why doesn't it contradict the alternating series test?
So if we take $\left|(-1)^{k-1}a_k\right|$ we get $|a_k| = \frac{1}{k}-\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}$. We know the first terms diverges as it is a harmonic series and the second term diverges as it's a $p$-series with $p = 1/2 < 1$. Hence, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}a_k$ diverges as required. Not too sure why it doesn't contradict the altermating series test. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $a_k$ is [**not monotonic**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C1%2Fn-%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%5E.5%7C) and therefore alternating serie test fails.

By limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{\sqrt k}$  we have that

$$\frac{\left|\frac{1}{k}-\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right|}{\frac1{\sqrt k}}= \left|\frac{\sqrt k}{k}-(-1)^k\right|\to 1$$

then the given series diverges.